# Datastructure to get data from external device

Tags: data-structures

I want to create a program to transfer data from an external device to the computer
It should save data in RAM first and then save them for ever.
What datastructure I must use?
All data are integers

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which operations you are plan to do on this data, for instance search for item, insert a new one, delete... Different data structures better suits for different matters. In general if nothing special is required - simple array is enought.